# How can I only allow these characters in the Powershell password generater?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

This function works nicely however, when it adds apecial characters I only want to allow these special characters
*^!+~

```
Function GenerateStrongPassword ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$PasswordLenght)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$PassComplexCheck = $false
do {
$newPassword=[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($PasswordLenght,1)
If ( ($newPassword -cmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") `
-and ($newPassword -cmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") `
-and ($newPassword -match "[\d]") `
-and ($newPassword -match "[^\w]")
)
{
$PassComplexCheck=$True
}
} While ($PassComplexCheck -eq $false)
return $newPassword
}

GenerateStrongPassword (16)
```

These are the special characters I want to allow

```
*^!+~
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need alphanumeric, e.g. A-Z_a-z + your specific NonAlphaNumeric chars, e.g. `*^!+~`

you can simply do:

```
(([char[]](0..255) -like '[A-Z]') + '*^!+~'.ToCharArray() | 
Get-Random -Count $PasswordLength) -join ""
```

Or you can use the `[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword` with `0` NonAlphaNumeric, e.g. `::GeneratePassword($PasswordLength,0)` and add it manually:

For Example:

```
Function GenerateStrongPassword ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$PasswordLength)
{
$Chars = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($PasswordLength,0) + '*^!+~'
$Password = ($Chars.ToCharArray() | Get-Random -Count $PasswordLength) -join ""
return $Password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need to do is to replace

`$newPassword -match "[^\w]"`

with

`$newPassword -match '[*^!+~]'`

Also, your other regexes and `if` statement can be streamlined / optimized away to yield the following assignment:

```bash
$PassComplexCheck = 
  $newPassword -cmatch '[\p{Lu}\s]' -and
  $newPassword -cmatch '[\p{Ll}]' -and
  $newPassword -match '\d' -and
  $newPassword -match '[*^!+~]'
```

That is:

- You can forgo an `if` statement by simply assigning the Boolean result of your expression directly to your `$PassComplexCheck` variable.
- In `[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]`, `A-Z` is redundant, because `\p{Lu}`, which represents *all* uppercase characters (not just English ones), implicitly comprises `A` through `Z` as well; the same applies analogously to `[a-z\p{Ll}\s]`
- Since `\s` is being matched by the initial regex, alongside uppercase letters, it needn't be matched again when looking for lowercase letters.
- `[\d]` needlessly wraps `\d` - matching a single digit - in `[...]` - the latter is only needed for *ranges* or *sets* of characters.